# reading google search history using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-search

I don't know whether this is possible or not.

I want to make a web app which will produce content based on the Google searches done by the user. I am using Google+ login for my Web APp.
I know google saves the search done by users. Is there any way to fetch them using javascript?

Comment: You want to fetch browser history on google chrome?

Comment: You can fetch the browser history using chrome history api [see here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history) but you can not get user specific searches by using thier logins

Answer (score 1):

This could help you..http://www.dicabrio.com/javascript/steal-history.php

And if you want to access the URLs of recently visited tabs using chrome.history API:
Pass an empty string as your query to the search() method of the chrome.history API. For example, this will log  most recently visited URLs to the console:

```
chrome.history.search({text: '', maxResults: 10}, function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(page) {
        console.log(page.url);
    });
});
```